# SIMD instruction emulation in WebAssembly?

Tags: rust, webassembly

I am investigating slowness in a WebAssembly project, and I wonder if SIMD instructions are being emulated somehow.  Here's a toy Rust library to exercise some SIMD operations:

```
use core::arch::wasm32::*;

#[no_mangle]
pub fn do_something(f: f32) -> f32 {
    let f4 = f32x4_splat(f);
    let mut a = f4;
    for _ in 0..100000 {
        a = f32x4_add(a, f4);
    }
    f32x4_extract_lane::<0>(a)
        + f32x4_extract_lane::<1>(a)
        + f32x4_extract_lane::<2>(a)
        + f32x4_extract_lane::<3>(a)
}
```

Then I build it with `cargo build --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown`.

Finally I run it with:

```
      const response = await fetch(WASM_FILE);
      const wasmBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
      const wasmObj = await WebAssembly.instantiate(wasmBuffer, {env:{}});
      function do_something() {
        wasmObj.instance.exports.do_something(0.00001);
        requestAnimationFrame(do_something);
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(do_something);
```

I suspect that the SIMD operations are being emulated, because I see this is the Chrome performance Call Tree:

[image: Performance trace of SIMD operations]

If the SIMD operations were being lowered to a single instruction--like I would expect--I wouldn't expect to see anything with `f32x4_add` in the profile trace.

Comment: Have you consulted [this](https://nickb.dev/blog/authoring-a-simd-enhanced-wasm-library-with-rust/) in terms of enabling the simd?

Comment: Did you enable the target feature `simd128`? (`-Ctarget-feature=+simd128` argument of rustc).

Comment: Looking at the [asm](https://godbolt.org/z/sG9csdcdf), It seems @ChayimFriedman is right. Add that target-feature, and the non-inlined calls disappear. Alternatively, try `wasm-opt -O4`, maybe that does something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a well known pitfall that if you don't enable the appropriate `target_feature` for SIMD functions, they're not inlined, causing a major overhead. [It's even documented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/codegen.html#the-target_feature-attribute).

The solution is to turn the `simd128` target feature on. You can do it by setting `RUSTFLAGS` (for example, [in `.cargo/config.toml`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#buildrustflags)), and pass the argument `-C target-feature=+simd128` to rustc.

Comment: Not well known to me!  Thanks.